# Low Battery Indicator for 2x AA Batteries

Tags: batteries, low-battery

How would I create a circuit which turns on an LED when the voltage goes below 2.5V? I am using 2x AA batteries

Comment: How "sharp" do you want the "knee" to be - ie how sudden the transition?. What standby current is acceptable? Why 2.5V - non-rechargeable batteries have some energy left at 2.5V (but of course the operated equipment may care. Softish knee with 2 transistors. Super sharp knee with TLV431 and 1 transistor (maybe 2) or TLV431 and LM339 comparator or ... .

Answer (score 4):

A simple comparator circuit is one way of doing it, something like this:

[image: Low Battery Detector]

You will have to adapt it as necessary for the lower voltage. Use a low voltage comparator (if not open drain output then switch the LED/resistor between output and ground) and change the zener for a low current voltage reference ([TL431](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tl431.pdf) would do okay).

You can use the TL431 mentioned directly as in this circuit (does high and low levels):

[image: Low Battery Detector 2]

The TL431 conveniently has a reference voltage of 2.5V so you don't need the R1A/R2A divider, you can just tie the ref input to Vbatt. If you want an even lower reference, there is also a 1.24V reference version, the [TLV431](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tlv431b.pdf).